# Know all the opened browsers in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to open a window on click of a button that will do some process but if user clicks on same button again it should not open the new window even after refreshing the opener page it should not open the new Window on click of the button.

When new window is closed then user can open the new window on click of the button.

That is the reason I am looking for the solution to get all the open browser instances so that I can restrict the user to open the same window again.

Comment: If the `window`s origin is the same you can use `localStorage` to achieve requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript `localStorage` object to set the open window information and it will be available until you close the browser.

Comment: localStorage will persist if you close your browser and then reopen it, you're thinking of sessionStorage